# Query max NSDate in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdate

Is there a way to query `NSDate` in `CoreData`. For example if I want an entity with the **highest** `NSDate` value? I see that `NSExpression` "max:" only takes an `NSNumber`.

Comment: you want fech object with max date from a entity ?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually ask SQL for just that value, not the object with that value:

```
NSExpression *date = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"date"];
NSExpression *maxDate = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:"
                                                  arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:maxDate]];
NSExpressionDescription *d = [[[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init] autorelease];
[d setName:@"maxDate"];
[d setExpression:maxSalaryExpression];
[d setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];

[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:d]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (objects == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
} else {
    if (0 < [objects count]) {
        NSLog(@"Maximum date: %@", [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"maxDate"]);
    }
}
```

more detail under Fetching Managed Objects -> Fetching Specific Values in the CoreData documentation.

or

Perfomed a query, ordered on Date field DESCENDING, and using setFetchLim it:1. 
    Its not perfect, but at least it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this directly in SQLite-- without fetching everything and then filtering the result, and without the complexity of `NSExpression`.

To get the one object that has the max date, do something like (assuming entity name `Entity` and date attribute `timeStamp`):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeStamp = self.@max.timeStamp"];
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
```

Do the fetch. You'll get (at most) one result, which will be the instance with the max date.

If you want to get just the date and not the entire managed object, add this before doing the fetch:

```
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[ @"timeStamp" ];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get it  with

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"tablename"];

fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"yourDate" ascending:NO]];

NSError *error = nil;

id person = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error].firstObject;
```